# RHEL: SELinux blocking python-ldap in apache

Tags: python, apache, centos, rhel

Dears,

I have on RHEL7 Apache 2.4 with mod_wsgi.
I have simple script with ldap-python to connect AD. If I run it from terminal it's working. When I tried run it from apache it cant connect to server. I tried disable SELinux and with disabled SELinux script working on apache. In permissive it not give any message in audit or messages. Any clue what can be wrong?

Comment: See [here](http://superuser.com/a/455990/511802) how to solve the problem with SELinux

Comment: After couple hours I fixed problem. First thing, I had excluded avc messages in audit config. Secound thing I had to switch httpd boolean **httpd_can_connect_ldap** to on. I hope it will be useful information for someone.

Comment: Mark your question as solved.